# Can I make a video of a running Java Swing application on the fly?

Tags: java, swing, video-capture

I have a Java swing GUI program that renders anywhere between 1 and 25 frames per second.
It is only one window and only one panel to which I do all the rendering, e.g. no other Swing components.

I need to be able to produce videos of test runs of my program as it runs.  The problem is that regular screen casting tools (e.g. 3rd party apps I start before running my code) often miss some of my frames and I need an accurate video.

I know how to use the Robot class to capture screenshots of my Java window, but I can't possibly be saving them to disk as I run, it will slow everything down too much.  Is there a way for me to use the Robot class (or maybe some other piece of code) to create a video of my window on the fly, while running my program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg wrapper in Java - [Xuggler](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop) and builtin Java [Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Here is sample code with Xuggler.

```
final Robot robot = new Robot();
final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
final Rectangle screenBounds = new Rectangle(toolkit.getScreenSize());

// First, let's make a IMediaWriter to write the file.
final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("output.mp4");

// We tell it we're going to add one video stream, with id 0,
// at position 0, and that it will have a fixed frame rate of
// FRAME_RATE.
writer.addVideoStream(0, 0,
 FRAME_RATE,
 screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height);

// Now, we're going to loop
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
for (int index = 0; index < SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR*FRAME_RATE.getDouble(); index++)
{
    // take the screen shot
   BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(screenBounds);

   // convert to the right image type
   BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen,
   BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

   // encode the image to stream #0
   writer.encodeVideo(0,bgrScreen,
   System.nanoTime()-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
   System.out.println("encoded image: " +index);

   // sleep for framerate milliseconds
  Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE.getDouble()));
}
// Finally we tell the writer to close and write the trailer if
// needed
writer.close();
```

Another option is [Screentoaster](http://www.screentoaster.com/) site - but I'm note sure what frame rate it provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program in Linux, you can take advantage of [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php). It is one of the better recording programs I have used with controls over the framerate and whatnot.

Comment: Sorry, running under Windows - don't like it very much either :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you adapt your program to dump the contents of your window after each update along with an accurate timestamp?  Then post process these into a movie if you need that.

That will give you full control.

Comment: Thorbjørn, thank you for the quick reply.
I was doing that already, but saving a file for every frame is rather slow.

Comment: It looks like JMF supports encoding several video formats.  Might be the way to go to be guaranteed that your video is accurate. http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/formats.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the visual changes, you can use some screen capping software:

Open source screenshot capper: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html (or just use plain alt+print screen, ctrl v for each state)
Open source video capper: http://camstudio.org/